# iOS Long Running Background service listening for multicast packets

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, mobile, background

Our company has a requirement to build an app that needs to have a service constantly running on the background listening for multicast packets and cache its content into variable size files to enhance user experience, the background service needs to run regardless of the app being running. The suggested approaches I saw here and in the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html) such as working with notifications wouldn't work as it is mandatory that these contents arrive over multicast which requires the socket to be constantly opened, also fetching using TCP would not be an option as it would increase network load which we're trying to avoid by using multicast. Another approach would be to register the app as VoIP so the app would be awake by the OS when new data arrives in that socket (which would be the multicast socket), but I'm not sure if that fits what apple considers to be a VoIP application, so I'm concerned we would have problems getting the app approved.

Any suggestions on how to implement this solution would be greatly appreciated!

**Edit:**
This is not an enterprise app, it is intended to be used on a dedicated WiFi and rely on our servers (deployed on the same WiFi) for multicast. It also needs to be public on the store for our customers to download.

Comment: Is this an enterprise app or is it going to be publicly available (you mention Apple approval, so I assume the latter).  If so then you can't use VoIP mode.  Also, if this app will operate over the Internet then you can't rely on multicast

Comment: Thanks for the follow up Paulw, this is intended to be used on a dedicated WiFi and rely on our servers (deployed on the same WiFi) for multicast. Still, this needs to be released on the store for our customers to download, and it's not an enterprise app.

Comment: Then I think you have requirements that are impossible to meet on iOS. You cannot guarantee that tasks will continue to run in the background on iOS in the way you are after.

Comment: I've inquired Apple about this, looking forward to hear from them, will post the answer here

Answer (score 0):

According to Apple:

> **1. Re: Long Running Background listening for multicast packets.
>   In response to Daniel Inc. on Oct 17, 2014 1:16 AM**
>
> Our company has a requirement to build an app that needs to have a
>   service constantly running on the background listening for multicast
>   packets [...]

AFAIK there's no supported way to do this on iOS.

> Another approach would be to register the app as VoIP so the app would
>   be awake by the OS when new data arrives in that socket (which would
>   be the multicast socket), but I'm not sure if that fits what Apple
>   considers to be a VoIP application, so I'm concerned we would have
>   problems getting the app approved.

Regardless of the approval issues, the VoIP infrastructure only supports TCP data sockets.

Share and Enjoy

Quinn "The Eskimo!" >
Apple Developer Relations, Developer Technical Support, Core OS/Hardware